# This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'ConsoleKeyInfo'

Tags: f#, functional-programming, unit-type

I just wanted to pause in an F# console application, so I wrote:

Console.ReadKey()

But this gives the warning: `This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'ConsoleKeyInfo'.`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You'll get pretty much the same warning in OCaml, BTW. You can disable it in F# with the --no-warn flag (though I'm not sure what the code number for that particular warning is).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Solution:

```
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Explanation: `Console.ReadKey()` returns an object of type 'ConsoleKeyInfo' but you're using it as a statement without assigning the return value to anything. So F# warns you that you're ignoring a value. `ignore` takes any type and returns nothing. It could be defined like this:

```
let ignore _ = ()
```

Comment: Alternatives: `ignore(Console.ReadKey())` or else `let _ = Console.ReadKey()`