# F# stop console from closing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F#: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'ConsoleKeyInfo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324947/f-this-expression-should-have-type-unit-but-has-type-consolekeyinfo)

I'm learning F# so i wrote a 3 lines of code in VS2010 and I want to see the result but the console closes. System.Console.Read System.Console.ReadKey or commands like that just don't work. Any other way to stop console from closing?

```
let x = 20
let y = x = 20
printf "is x 20? %d" y
System.Console.ReadKey
```

Comment: Can you see the F# interactive console?

Comment: No the console window just pop out and closes. I didn't know there is an interactive console :). But now i do. An amazing thing! Now coding in console.Thank you Tobi

Comment: Using Ctrl+F5 to run your snippets may help.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/324962/995246)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you need to do

```
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

at the end to require a key press to exit - the `()` is to actually call the function and `|> ignore` is because you don't care about the result

Comment: I was using script file (.fsx)..now I tried with your solution in source file (.fs) and it worked. Thank you John