# Cannot Resolve console.readkey call

Tags: .net, f#

I am having extreme difficulty with this line "`console.readkey(true)`" as the last line in my Visual F# file! I have "open system" at the top of the file but the compiler thinks that `Console` is an undefined namespace.

Comment: Added tag F#, corrected typo & highlighted code

Comment: Is it `console` or `Console` in your code? F# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: This definitely needs a better title.  Just about everyone who posts a question on F# "needs help with a F# file" - why is your question different.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> console.readkey(true)
> ```

F#, like C#, is case sensitive. So try

```
Console.ReadKey(true)
```

Comment: I thank u for trying to jhelp me but the capital C is not the problem. Here is my code from the latest attempt to get this right :#light  
System.Console.WriteLine("Please Press 1")
System.Console.WriteLine("Please Press 2")
System.Console.WriteLine("Please Press 3")
let input =  System.Console.ReadLine( )
 
if input.Equals("1") then
System.Console.WriteLine "Hey you must be Steven!"
else if input.Equals("2") then
System.Console.WriteLine "Hey you must be Markie!"
else  
System.Console.WriteLine "Okay you must have hung up!"
System.Console.ReadKey(true)

Comment: I mam sorry people but my problem isn't resolved yet. I STILL have a problem with that line "System.Console.ReadKey(true)" in my Visual F# file.

Comment: @user3803936 Please rework your question with 1. a (short) demonstration of the problem, and 2. the extract compiler error message(s) (and make sure it is clear which line is being referenced by the compiler).

Comment: 1. System.Console.ReadKey(true) yields a compiler error saying that the expression i s not the expected Unit but a ConsoleKeyInfo. Now what's up with that?

Comment: @user3803936 You need to do something with the result. Eg. `Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/324962/67392)).